# "Access is Denied" error installing Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

I tried to install the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64, but it failed with error below:

```
Setup could not install following component:

Windows Phone Emulator x64
```

The Windows event log shows the error:

```
The Virtual Machine Monitor service failed to start due to the following error: Access is denied.
```

Does anybody have experience with this error?

Comment: You have an existing virtual device installed. try removing completely and try again.

Comment: i don't have any virtual device installed before. Hardware-Assisted Virtualization Detection Tool said that "Hardware-assisted virtualization is not enabled on this computer". but i checked bios and this already set enable. More info from log: 
MSI (s) (94:50) [12:41:57:808]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 6920 (0x1B08).
MSI (s) (94:20) [12:41:57:831]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (94:20) [12:41:57:832]: Hello, I'm your 64bit Elevated custom action server.
vmmmsm_custom: Running custom action CA_InstallVMMDriver
vmmmsm_custom: Error starting VMM service, E = 5

Comment: Finally, i solved this issue by disabling Virtualization feature in bios. Uncheck "Enable intel virtualization technology" (dell m4600). Now i can play with windows phone emulator. Thanks all!